# How to get Bigcommerce Abandoned cart details?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to get the Abandoned cart details from the Bigcommerce website using REST API.

Can anyone suggest how we can achieve this. I can able to get the orders and customers using their REST API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's presently no API endpoints for the Abandoned Cart information. "Abandoned cart" is currently a purely core app function that has no exposure.

If you'd like to reference a company that has found a workaround, you can see something like [Klaviyo](https://www.klaviyo.com/).